# Selenium IDE Selecting drop down box item in infopath

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide, infopath2010

I am trying to get selenium to select items from a infopath dropdown list box

I have a simple test infopath form with a single dropdown list box listing car makers.

I record the steps using selenium of opening the form, selecting a car maker and submitting the form and it runs correctly. When I go to play back the test suite I get the following from the log

```
[info] Playing test case Untitled
[info] Executing: |open | /Tdata/Car%20makers/Forms/AllItems.aspx | |
[info] Executing: |clickAndWait | id=idHomePageNewItem-WPQ2 | |
[info] Executing: |select | id=FormControl_V1_I1_D1 | label=volvo |
[error] Option with label 'volvo' not found
[info] Test case failed
[info] Test suite completed: 1 played, 1 failed
```

When I inspect the element using firebug I see the following

```
<select style="direction:ltr" title="" tabindex="0" 
originalid="V1_I1_D1" formid="FormControl" viewdatanode="2"
direction="ltr" wrapped="true" class="k_CL3j7VgxtmnkG4un_0
b_CL3j7VgxtmnkG4un_0 o_CL3j7VgxtmnkG4un_0 z_CL3j7VgxtmnkG4un_0"
scriptclass="DropDownList" id="FormControl_V1_I1_D1" onblur="return
(DropDownList.OnBlur(this, event));" onfocus="return
DropDownList.OnFocus(this, event));" onchange="return
(DropDownList.OnChange(this, event));">
```

in firebug there is plus sign next to this if I click on it I can then see the options

```
    <option selected="" value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
    <option value="fiat">fiat</option>
    <option value="GM">GM</option>
    <option value="datsun">datsun</option>
    <option value="volvo">volvo</option>
</select>
```

and my selenium script will run correctly if I press this plus sign before running the script. So I am thinking that this is created by Javascript. I tried SelectandWait in selenium and this didn't work. How would I get selenium to trigger the Javascript to create the dropdown box list, so it can then be selected?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if that list (with volvo in it) is supplied via an ajax call.

Comment: Is there a way to trigger that ajax call?

Comment: See if the list is populated on page load. You might just have add a waitFor after the clickAndWait in case the ajax fires at page load. fireEvent is the way to trigger javascript events.

Comment: I tried the clickAndWait but this just timed out. What would be my target and value for the fireEvent?

Comment: Thanks DMart, It was the fireEvent that worked, I just had to run the IDE at slow. I tried the fireEventandWait, this gave a time out error, but the process still worked. I am looking at adding a pause after the fireEvent.

Comment: FireEvent and wait or maybe a WaitFor after the fireEvent...